# Abelian Variety Commutative

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, abelian-varieties

I have a question about a step in a proof from Lang's "Abelian Varieties"  (page 20):

[image: Variety]

By definition an abelian variety $A$ over field $k$ is a proper smooth $k$-group scheme that is irreducible.

In the Theorem 1 where we have to show that an abelian variety is commutative the author says in the red tagged line that it 
suffice to show that

$$\dim T \le \dim A$$

for $A,T$ as lopological spaces.

Here $T$ is the locus if $(x, yxy^{-1}) \in A \times A$.

My question is why this suffice for the proof?

Comment: $D = \{(x,x),x\in A\}$ is a subvariety of $T$ of dimension $\dim(A)$. The main point is the dimension theorem, can you expand on it

Comment: @reuns: ok so then we conclude $D=T$ and therefore $x =yxy^{-1}$ by definition of $T$. so we are done. Thank you

Comment: At first we don't know that $A$ is abelian so what is it supposed to be $\dim(T)+\dim(e\times A)$ ?

Comment: @reuns: You mean it is supposed at first that $\dim(T)+\dim(e\times A) \ge 2 \dim(A)$ since $T$ contains the diagonal. Or do you have another estimation in mind?

Comment: @reuns: You mean that it is supposed at first that $\dim(T)+\dim(e\times A) \ge 2 \dim(A)$ since $T$ contains the diagonal? Or do you have another estimation in mind?

Comment: The key argument you need is $\dim(T)+\dim(e\times A) \le \dim(A \times A) = 2 \dim(A)$. I'm asking how do you obtain that. When $A$ isn't a commutative group then $T \times (e \times A) \mapsto A \times A, ( (x,y xy^{-1}), (e,a)) \mapsto (x,y xy^{-1} a)$ doesn't have to be injective.

Comment: @reuns:The author - if I understood him correctly - argued only using underlying topological spaces. Then he showed that that $T \cap e \times A= (e,e)$ set theoretically and then calculated the dimension the union $T \cup (e \times A)$. Here I'm not sure: I guess that under given conditions the dimension formula should hold: $\dim(T \cup (e \times A))= \dim(T) + \dim(e \times A) -\dim(T \cap (e \times A))$? But here I have to confess that I don't found a source which explicitely describe under which general conditions the dimension formula for varieties bome applicable.

Comment: @reuns: What I really don't understand is his argument that $T \cap (e \times A)=(e,e)$. He argues that ***since $A$ complete*** a point $(e,a) \in T \cap (e \times A)$ has a preimage under the map $(x,y) \mapsto (x, yxy^{-1})$. Why does completeness imply this? Do you see it? I'm working with following definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_variety

Comment: $T$ is the Zariski closure of $S=\{ (x,yx y^{-1}), (x,y) \in A\times A\}$, it is obvious that $S  \cap (e \times A) = (e,e)$. The main point is really that $\dim(T)+\dim(e\times A) \le \dim(A \times A)$, how does he achieve this ?

Comment: @reuns:Doesn't it come from following estimation: $$\dim(T) + \dim(e \times A)= \dim(T) + \dim(e \times A) -\dim(T \cap (e \times A))= \dim(T \cup (e \times A)) \le \dim A \times A$$?

The first equality is by $\dim(T \cap (e \times A))= 0$ as seen before, the second by the mentioned dimension formula and the third since $T \cup (e \times A) \subset A \times A$. Or do I have overseen some cruical point?

The first equality is by $\dim(T \cap (e \times A))= 0$ as seen before, the second by the mentioned dimension formula and the third since $T \cup (e \times A) \subset A \times A$.

Comment: @reuns: Or do I have overseen some cruical point? 
One question about the argument for $T \cap (e \times A)=(e,e)$: Where the author concretely used that $A$ is complete here?

Answer (score 3):

Over $\Bbb{C}$ it is a matter of complex analysis :

Let $A$ be a connected compact complex manifold which is also a group whose operations are given by holomorphic functions. Let $\phi$ be a chart from a neighborhood of $0 \in \Bbb{C}^n$ to $1 \in A$.

- For every $a \in A$ and $v \in \Bbb{C}^n$ let $$\rho(a) v = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\phi^{-1}(a\phi(tv)a^{-1})}{t}$$

  Looking at the Jacobian of $\phi$ and multiplication by $a$ shows $v \mapsto \rho(a) v$ is $\Bbb{C}$-linear. Thus $a \mapsto \rho(a)$ is an holomorphic map $A \to GL_n(\Bbb{C})$. [Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)#On_compact_Riemann_surfaces) implies $\rho$ is constant, thus $\rho(a) v = v$.
- Transport the $\Bbb{R}^{2n}$ metric to the neighborhood of $1 \in A$. For any $v \in\Bbb{C}^n$ there is a unique function $\exp_v : (-r,r) \subset \Bbb{R} \to A$ such that $\exp_v(0)=1, \exp_v(t+s) = \phi(tv) \exp_v(s)+O(t^2)$. Comparing the real dimension shows any element closed to $1\in A$ is of the form $x=\prod_{j=1}^J \exp_{v_j}(1)$ for some $v_j$. And since $a \exp_{v_j}(t+u) a^{-1}=  \phi(t\rho(a) v) a \exp_{v_j}(u) a^{-1}+O(t^2)$ we have $a \exp_{v_j}(t) a^{-1}= \exp_{\rho(a) v_j}(t)$ and $axa^{-1} =x$

  > Whence the group law is commutative.

The algebraic version for compact group varieties over algebraically closed field is similar, Liouville being replaced by that a morphism from a complete variety to an affine variety must be [constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626817/morphisms-from-a-proper-scheme-to-the-affine-line-over-a-field-must-be-constant).

Comment: Do you even need Liouville's theorem? Any non-constant holomorphic map $A\to\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ has open image by the open mapping theorem, and closed image because $A$ is compact. Since $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is connected this implies that $A\to\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is compact, which is ridiculous. Also, why aren't you done at this stage? Isn't it well-known that the kernel of the map $G\to\mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$ is $Z(G)$? So, if this map is trivial then $G=Z(G)$? Also you should be careful in saying that a map from a complete variety to an affine variety is constant.

Comment: This is true if you assume that the complete variety is geometrically connected. Otherwise you could just take a finite disjoint union of points. Over other fields you also have to careful to show that the map $A\to\mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$ is algebraic. To do this you have to work functorially, and this gets a bit finnicky. I only know one source that does this rigorously. Usually people use the rigidity lemma, which is what the OP's reference seems to be using.

Comment: Tks. The spirit is that complex analysis is the only tool I have to approach those things. For Liouville the idea is not to use it but to reprove it in a different framework : for an entire bounded function $z^2 f(1/z)$ is holomorphic so $f$ is analytic on the Riemann sphere, which is compact, so $f$ is constant, by the open mapping or the maximum modulus. So you are saying the rigidity lemma would be the direct algebraic generalization to over fields.

Comment: I would look at $R=G(k[[t]]) \subset k[[t]]^m$ and for $f(t) = a+bt+O(t^2)$ if $a = 1$ then $b\in \mathfrak{g}$, the map $G \to GL(\mathfrak{g})$ is obvious, for its kernel, I would look at $S = G(\overline{k(t)}\cap k[[t]])$ so that I can think to its elements as functions $k \to G$. Is it the correct approach ? Usually they do it with the differentials of the coordinates, so maybe I should look more carefully at what it means that conjugaison by $a$ acts trivially on those differentials.

Comment: It's even more subtle than that I'm afraid. You can see a discussion of this starting on Page 9 of this: http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/249CS15Page/handouts/abvarnotes.pdf Be forewarned that if you're not very scheme-happy then this might make you sad.